# Visually show variation between classified maps - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have classified a satellite image using four techniques. I want to show how much variation (e.g., deviation or similarity) between maps there is for each pixel. For example, if a pixel is classified as the same class by all four maps (4/4), I want it to be blue. The less agreement between the maps, I want the color of the pixels to be red.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the [Cell Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm) tool if you have a Spatial Analyst
Extension. Under the `statistics_type (options)` there is a `Variety` option that may need to use

> - VARIETY—The variety (number of unique values) of the inputs will be
>   calculated.

The input accepts many rasters to evaluate the variation among the rasters and give unique values. Then you can give them the color you want for those similar and changed cells.